# CCMoveTo not working, node/scene issue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a CCLayer class called SuccessLayer. It gets added to the scene when the level is complete, like so:

```
SuccessLayer *successLayer = [SuccessLayer node];
[self addChild:successLayer];
```

In SuccessLayer, I want to have a rock fly by, I'm trying to achieve that with this:

```
-(void)onEnter{
    Asteroid *asteroid = [Asteroid spriteWithFile:@"rocks.png"];
    asteroid.position = ccp(0, 500);
    [self addChild:asteroid];
    CCMoveTo *move = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:2.0 position:ccp(1000, 0)];
    [asteroid runAction:move];}
```

However, it seems `CCMoveTo` isn't working. I see the sprite sitting at its initial coordinates, but nothing more. What am I missing here? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sovled the problem by casting it as a CCSprite (is that the correct way to say it?)

```
CCSprite *asteroid = [Asteroid spriteWithFile:@"rocks.png"];
```

`Asteroid` is already a subclass of CCSprite, so I have no idea why this works, but it allows me to run actions on it now.

Comment: Maybe it worked in this particular situation, but casting really shouldn't make any difference. I would love to figure out why it does make a difference in this particular case.
See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15120391/201863

Answer (score 3):

[super onEnter];

any coco's onSomething, you should super onSomething.

Comment: Sorry forgot to include that code. Its already there though :(

Comment: Thanks! That's a crucial point that I forgot, and any action of the node's children will not work.