# runAction do not works for sprites coming from CCSpriteBatchNode

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am using Cocos2d 2.1rc0.

I have this project that was working perfectly when I was not using CCSpriteBatchNode. Then I decided to use batch nodes to reduce draw calls and my problems started.

A lot of stuff is not working well. reorderChild is one. Another one is runAction and without runAction Cocos is useless.

This is an example of a method that works without batchNodes and do not work with it.

```
// move/rotate all objects

for (int i=0; i<[allObjects count]; i++) {

        Card *object = [allObjects objectAtIndex:i];
        [object stopAllActions];

        CGPoint center = object.position;
        center.x = center.x + 100;
        center.y = center.y - 200;

        CCMoveTo *moveAction = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.3f position:ccp(center.x, center.y)];
        CCRotateTo *rotateAction = [CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:0.3 angle:0.0f];

        CCSpawn *action = [CCSpawn actions:moveAction, rotateAction, nil];

        [object runAction:[CCSequence actions: action,
                             [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:0.1f],
                             nil]];
}
```

Exactly nothing happens.

I have tried to eliminate the CCSpanw and use runAction directly just with move and nothing works. If I use regular sprites, it works.

Objects in that array derive from a CCSprite based class.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: Is object.isRunning true ?

Comment: strangely YES, but there's no action running when this method is invoked. Why is this yes is another mystery. Anyway I have added a line [object stopAllActions] (see my question) and there is no change.

Comment: isRunning is a basic CCNode property, is YES between onEnter and onExit. hmmm ... no more ideas at the moment, will do a quick test with one of my batch nodes to see if i can dupe your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I have discovered the problem. You have to cast the class to the object when it is extracted from the array... The idea came from this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885055/ccmoveto-not-working-node-scene-issue?rq=1 see my answer.

Comment: Can you post the code for the Card class? If it's a lot, remove all methods except overridden super class (CCSprite) methods and the initializers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is to cast the class to the object extracted from the array...

instead of

```
Card *object = [allObjects objectAtIndex:i];
```

this

```
Card *object = (Card *)[allObjects objectAtIndex:i];
```

Comment: hahaha ... oh well, i'll keep this in mind. I had confirmed for myself that actions were running just seconds ago.

Comment: thanks anyway. For some bizarre reason this was working without casting before but now it just works after casting. Pretty bizarre.

Comment: This is really weird. Can you please check by single-stepping over and into the runAction code what happens there if you don't cast?

Comment: I have replaced the runAction with just a ccMoveTo and nothing happens. The sprites continue on the same position. If I run this with regular sprites, it works.

Comment: what happens if you step into the runaction method?

Comment: never tried that because It would show cocos code and I would have to understand what is going on down there, but the line itself does nothing, does not move the sprite that stays there on the same position. I replace it with a regular sprite and the line moves the sprite.

Answer (score 0):

After double-checking in a clean project that this isn't a weird side-effect of some kind, I have to say there's something fishy about your project. Hard to tell what, though.

What I did: create a sprite-batch, add a sprite to it, also store it in an array. In a scheduled method I'm receiving the sprite from the array (not casting) and run your action sequence posted above. It works fine, as expected.

**The casting should not make any difference.** Batched or non-batched sprite should not make any difference either.

If it does, something really weird is going on. After all the card object is the same with or without casting. If it were not actually running the runAction method, you'd be receiving an "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error. But that's not the case.

Try again without casting, after rebooting your device, your machine, cleaning the project in Xcode and rebuilding. Also test in debug and release configurations. I've had the weirdest issues that were gone after doing one of the above, and definitely all of the above. If that doesn't fix things, you can be sure it's a problem with the code (memory leak is my alltime favorite) or the project settings (ie uncommon compiler optimizations sometimes can have side-effects).

Step into the runAction method if it really doesn't run the action - I'm sure it will add the action to the action manager. Try with and without casting to see if there really is a different code path taken. I doubt it.

Comment: I tried all this without success. I am using ARC on my part of the code, as Cocos2D is not ARC yet. Have you tried the reorderChild stuff with batched nodes. Does not work for me. I don't know what the problem is but casting solves the problem. I agree this is weird, as casting in that case in theory would have no effect.

Comment: Have you tried running the analyzer? Perhaps that will give a clue. How did you setup ARC, as a static library or with -fno-Objc-arc? Have you perhaps updated the cocos2d code at some point in time (and therefore have some new cocos2d source files without that flag)?
Haven't tried reorderChild but all of that tells me this is just the tip of the iceberg of an underlying (nasty) issue that might rear its ugly head in other places as well.

Comment: -fno-objc-arc flag. I have started this from a clean Cocos2D project (file, new project, cocos2D). All Cocos2D source files have the compiler flag. There's no leak. The app is working beautifully. Please try the reorderChild and see if it works for you. Try batched sprites over a background that is a batched sprite itself.

Comment: two different batches, or the same?

Comment: two different batches. I think this question of yours can be the key.

Comment: I'll try it in a couple minutes.